# Passing an interface address through an outer layer and into nested inner layers

Tags: oop, plc, twincat

I am attempting to create my own OOP event logger. I know TwinCAT had their own, however there is some functionality that I need that TwinCAT's event logger does not have. If I have an interface of I_Logger being inserted into an outer FB, I am needing to pass the address down into my nested FBs so that all my FBs have access to it. The only kicker is that I need the outer class to be dynamic. Since my inner classes are made up of devices and components, and then my outer layer can be a station or a zone, I am working on my framework to cater to this. Devices are the lowest level. Components are grouping of devices, assemblies are groupings of components and devices, stations are groupings of any of the previous, so on and so forth.

I have attempted to use a decorator pattern and chaining methods to try and retrieve the address of the logger but that has not worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to explicitly set the logger used by the top-level FB because you may have to use several such loggers in the same application?  Are your nested FBs already receiving some form of context from the top-level one (i.e. a reference to the parent FB other form of shared context all FBs of the sub-hierarchy have in common)?

Comment: @Fred In the case of using multiple loggers, I create a wrapper manager class that encapsulates the loggers and would use the same I_Logger interface. Right now, my nested FBs are not receiving anything from the parent. I have attempted to create a base class that all items can be of with FB_init taking in THIS^ and assigning the interface, however, doing that, I found it to only go one level up. I did this by creating the classes Logger, Inner, and outer. If outer was instantiated by outer(Logger), and inner, being inside outer, was called by inner(THIS^), inner had no access to Logger.